# Web API 2- Data Annotations Validation-No Duplicates in the Request

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am using WEB API 2. 
In my request I pass the request as Collection of Mytype

```
MyType has following properties:

Id(int),
PaymentId(int).
```

I need the following validation. Every Id of the request should be Unique.

Do I need to write custom validation or Is there any builtin DataAnnotationValidation exist for that?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is writing a model class inheriting IValidatableObject or writing a custom validation attribute for the entire model. Web API will validate your model on the custom validation logic.

```
public class MyModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<MyType> MyTypes { get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        foreach(var myType in this.MyTypes)
        {
            // do validation logic
            if (error)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("All Ids must be unique!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```